# Why do speechmarks around an array declaration in bash cause it to have zero length?

Tags: arrays, bash

I came across a curious error in a bash script recently. The code was failing with a divide by zero error. The script was dividing by the length of a declared array, and the array was definitely populated by strings. For some reason, the array had length zero, despite being populated. An example script reproducing the problem is given below.

```
#!/bin/bash

aCoolFunction(){

    declare -a messageSpeechMarks="(
    'a'
    'b'
    'c'
    )";

    declare -a messageNoSpeechMarks=(
    'a'
    'b'
    'c'
    );

    for item in ${messageSpeechMarks[@]}
    do
        echo "${item}"
    done

    echo "Length of messageSpeechMarks: ${#messageSpeechMarks[@]}"
    echo "Length of messageNoSpeechMarks: ${#messageNoSpeechMarks[@]}"
}

aCoolFunction
```

When run using GNU bash 4.3.11(1) on Linux Mint, this gives the output:

```
a
b
c
Length of messageSpeechMarks: 0
Length of messageNoSpeechMarks: 3
```

As you can see, simply removing speech marks from before and after the array declaration fixes the problem and results in the array having the correct length. Can anyone explain to me what the difference between `declare -a array=( ... )` and `declare -a array="( ... )"`? What does the declaration with speech marks actually mean? Thanks.

Comment: With GNU Bash-4.2 gives me length 3 for both cases

Comment: Same here.. it gives 3 for both

Comment: In 3.2 as well. What version of `bash` are you using?

Comment: I can reproduce this on 4.3.11(1)-release. You can loop over the array elements just fine, but the element count is 0. Looks like a bug.

Comment: I'm using GNU Bash 4.3.11(1). I have edited the post to reflect this.

Comment: It seems to be already fixed; I get length of 3 for both in 4.3.30.

Comment: Is it simply a bug, or is there a conceptually a difference between the two declarations? Is one more correct than the other? I scoured the internet for information, but could never find a reference where the array="( ... ) version.

Comment: Interestingly, this may be the first time I've encountered the term "speechmarks". I've always called them "quotation marks" or "double quotes".

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf copy-pasting or typing in a similar example from scratch makes no difference, I still get exactly what OP says. Did you copy-paste it exactly as is (i.e. without dropping the function definition)?

Answer (score 1):

Arguably, there should be a difference between:

```
declare a="(1 2 3)"
```

and

```
a="(1 2 3)"
```

In the second case, `a` is being set to the quoted string `(1 2 3)` so that the parentheses do not have syntactic significance.

In the `declare` statement, in contrast, one might expect the argument will be dequoted before `declare` is executed, so that `declare` will see the parenthesis as an array marker. But on the other hand, it is likely that the expectation is that in

```
declare a=(1 2 3)
```

`a=(1 2 3)` will be treated as a single declaration rather than as three separate arguments.

But if the argument is dequoted, how can one `declare` (or `export` or `local`) a scalar variable whose value starts with an open parenthesis?

The ambiguity reflects the difficulty of parsing `bash` builtins, particularly since there is no standard syntax to guide us.

`zsh` sidesteps the issue by not allowing the assignment of arrays in a `typeset` declaration. `ksh` works the same way as the versions of `bash` reported in the OP: It parses `a=...` and `typeset a=...` the same way (so that in both cases, the quotes inhibit recognition of the parentheses as array markers).

Comment: Why would you expect the argument to be dequoted in either case? I can write `declare a="foo bar"`, and it will set `$a` to the string `'foo bar'`. If I want the string to contain parentheses, I can write `declare a="(foo bar)"`; if the shell reached into the string literal and interpreted the parentheses as special characters, I'd be surprised and annoyed.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I would certainly expect the argument to be dequoted, so that `declare a="(foo bar)"` resulted in `a` having the value `(foo bar)` rather than having the value `"(foo bar)"`, which is precisely what the bash manual means when it talks about quote removal. The question is whether it is dequoted before being passed to `declare`, so that `declare` can know whether or not the parentheses were escaped. Since declare is a builtin, it is possible to pass it that information but I agree that it is a bit odd. Still, the OP and the reported "fix" to bash imply that other opinions exist.